# How can I get a vfat pendrive to automount as posixovl filesystem?

Tags: mount, automounting, fuse, vfat

I'm using Kubuntu. I'd like to use my pendrive primarily for storing various data for my Linux (and not losing metadata like permissions and ownerships), but I don't want to exclude access to it from Windows - e.g. if I hand it to someone at a print shop to have some photos printed, I don't expect them to have anything to read ext3 or such.

It appears [fuse-posixovl](http://man.devl.cz/man/1/mount.posixovl) provides such functionality, as a modern replacement to antiquated umsdos: the FS is visible as generic FAT from Windows hosts, while providing about all Linux features when used on Linux.

Except mounting the partition is a two-step operation, first mounting the vfat, and then mounting the posixovl overlay right over it. In essence without automount the invocation looks something like this:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/pendrive -t vfat
mount.posixovl /mnt/pendrive
# ...perform operations on the pendrive
umount /mnt/pendrive
umount /mnt/pendrive
```

Automount obviously handles the first step, and I can "safely remove" the volume twice to have it vanish from the file manager, but how do I get it to mount as posixovl (2nd step) when I plug it in?

Comment: You can use udev to run any arbitrary command when a device is connected (based on e.g. make/model/serial number). Maybe that can be pressed into service?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I guess the solution would be along these lines but I'm pretty much clueless about udev (and not breaking it for updates etc, as it's probably wrapped in several abstraction layers).